# Orientation : Landscape Lock - HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to set one page on my application to `orientation:landscape` and this is how i am doing it.  My code below doesn't do the trick. What am i missing out?

```
 @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 1281px) 
and (orientation : potrait)
{
    html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to rotate the body perhaps and its portrait

Comment: why would you want that? your content would not fit in the portrait view

Comment: @Highdef, actually put the page in landscape :)

Comment: @BarbuBarbu, it looks cleaner and simple in landscape view

Comment: you are simply having a syntax error `portrait` instead of `potrait`